# How to use R Random forests to reduce attributes having no discrete classes?

Tags: r, statistics, machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest

I want to use Random forests for attribute reduction. One problem I have in my data is that I don't have discrete class - only continuous, which indicates how example differs from 'normal'. This class attribute is a kind of distance from zero to infinity. 
Is there any way to use Random forest for such data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be no problem -- RF will just switch to regression mode. Use `randomForest` function from the `randomForest` package.
To get object similarity with `proximity=TRUE` argument, like:

```
randomForest(Sepal.Length~.,data=iris,proximity=TRUE)$proximity
```

To get node-purity (Gini-index like) attribute importance:

```
randomForest(Sepal.Length~.,data=iris)$importance[,"IncNodePurity"]
```

To get mean MSE increase (accuracy-decrease like) attribute importance:

```
randomForest(Sepal.Length~.,data=iris,importance=TRUE)$importance[,"%IncMSE"]
```

Comment: Variable importance would work better for me than proximity. Maybe description of my classification attribute was a bit misleading, but I know what should I explore.

Comment: I have extended the answer to cover that.

Comment: Ok, I've also changed the question to use 'data-mining' vocabulary. Shouldn't you use `importance=TRUE` also in the second statement?

Comment: No, because node-purity is calculated along with forest creation, so randomForest creates this element always, while MSE increase needs shuffling and classifying OOB objects.

Comment: You can carry out variable elimination from random forest, using the varSelRF package: http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/varSelRF/man/plot.varSelRF.html